# Does Canon Powershot SX520HS support tethering?

Tags: tethering, powershot

I'd like to experiment with stop motion. It's best to use tethering so avoid having to touch the camera to capture. I know the sx520hs does not support wireless but it does have a mini usb port for transferring. Does anyone know if the sx520hs supports tethering via mini usb? What software would work to do tethered capture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say 100% for sure (absence of evidence is not necessarily evidence of absence, after all), but apparently no, the SX520HS does not support tethering.

1. It doesn't show up in any [list of cameras that TetherTools has solutions/support for](https://www.tethertools.com/?s=sx520hs#). While they aren't exhaustive of all cameras that support tethering, their list is *very* broad.
2. [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/canon/comments/730r6e/remote_shutter_for_powershot_sx520_hs/) indicates that there isn't even a remote shutter trigger option available, let alone tethering.
3. [This Canon Community thread](https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/PowerShot/Is-there-a-remote-shutter-button-for-the-Canon-SX520-HS/td-p/213137), while not authoritative from Canon itself, says the same thing as the Reddit thread — there is no remote trigger available.

Based on the lack of even a remote shutter trigger (which might actually be enough for stop-motion purposes) and lack of TetherTools support, I seriously doubt the camera supports tethering.